# Can not clone a repository with ssh from bitbucket

Tags: ssh, git, clone

I have a bit bucket repository and I am trying to clone it using SSH. I followed the instruction here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

and I can get see that I can get access to the repository:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

but when I try to clone my repository, I am getting this error:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:MyName/MyRepo.git
Cloning into 'MyRepo'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It should be noted that I have several accounts on Bitbucket (for the different organizations where I work). So maybe the bitbucket using the wrong ssh key to clone the repository. How can I force the bitbucket to use the correct one or search for the correct one on my PC?

I am using windows 10.

## Edit1

Option `-v` doesn't show any more information:

```
git clone -v git@bitbucket.org:MyName/MyRepo.git
Cloning into 'MyRepo'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

## Edit 2

here is the output of requested command in comments:

```
 ssh -T -v git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::22c5:2ef4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_eda5298d7e 60ddf9423977
debug1: no match: conker_eda5298d7e 60ddf9423977
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaXXXXX
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: MyName@DESKTOP-KQ34PDP RSA SHA256:ypYnv30FvYLDVY1c2p7PngPPjy4uPR8pn4yXXXXXX agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyName/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: MyName@DESKTOP-KQ34PDP RSA SHA256:ypYnv30FvYLDVY1c2p7PngPPjy4uPR8pn4yXXXXXXX agent
debug1: Server accepts key: MyName@DESKTOP-KQ34PDP RSA SHA256:ypYnv30FvYLDVY1c2p7PngPPjy4uPR8pn4yXXXXXX agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([2406:da00:ff00::22c5:2ef4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3016, received 2276 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
12841.5
debug1: Exit status 0
received
```

The key that I build and used has a different name which is not presented above. Also in my C:\Users\MyName/.ssh folder, I do not have any other key or file (only two files, the known host file and the key that I am planning to use to login into Bitbucket)

## Edit 3

The situation in git bash is different. in Git bash the following command fails:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What is the difference between what I can see in PowerShell and git bash?

Comment: Does option `-v` show more information about the error?

Comment: @Bodo No more information, please see the edited question.

Comment: Did you create different SSH keys on the same PC for different accounts? Run `ssh -T -v git@bitbucket.org`  and check the output for the key that is used. Then check if this key has been uploaded to bitbucket for the user that is supposed to access the repo.

Comment: Are you running each of those commands in "Git Bash" or in standard Windows Cmd or PowerShell? What's the output of `where.exe ssh` in the latter?

Comment: @user1686: the result of running the suggested command is:  where.exe ssh
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

Answer (score 1):

When Git is installed on Windows 10, you end up with two separate copies of OpenSSH – one bundled with Windows (a native port done by Microsoft) and one bundled with Git (an MSYS-based port). The two are mostly, but not fully, compatible: e.g. they translate "~/.ssh/id_rsa" in the same way, but they use different ways of starting and accessing the ssh-agent.

So if the SSH key was placed in a non-default location, the SSH client relies on finding it through ssh-agent rather than directly from a file – and if you used the Windows `ssh-add` to load it, it won't be seen by the MSYS `ssh.exe` and vice versa.

To make Git always use the Windows version of ssh.exe, set `GIT_SSH` to the appropriate path:

```
PS> $env:GIT_SSH = "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"
```

```
$ export GIT_SSH="/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
```

(You can make it use PuTTY's `plink.exe` the same way; it will then load keys from PuTTY's Pageant.)

Alternatively, move your key file to one of the default locations listed in your `ssh -v` output, such as `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (i.e. `C:\Users\MyName\.ssh\id_rsa`).